# Best way to handle mongodb data for ejs file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, ejs

I'd like to render mainly mongoDB data and an array. What I want to do is allow my ejs file to use the components inside the database. 
Here is my code:

```
 //Array to store all restaurants
 var restArray = [];

 //Need database restaurant schema 
 var databaseArray = [];

 //Find the restaurant in the database,
 //If not there create one.
 var findOrCreate = function() {
     Restaurant.findOne({
             nameOfRest: this.nameOfRest
         })
         .then(exist => {
             if (!exist) {

                 this.save()
                     .then(result => {
                         databaseArray.push(result);
                     })
                     .catch(err => {
                         console.log(err);
                     })
             } else {
                 databaseArray.push(exist);
             }
         })
         .catch(err => {
             debugger;
             console.log(err);
         })
 }
 //Go through each restaurant and put in function.
 restArray.forEach(function(restArr) {

     var tempRest = new Restaurant({
         nameOfRest: restArr.restaurant.name,
         favoriteFoods: [],
     });
     //databaseArray.push(tempRest);

     findOrCreate.call(tempRest);
 });
  //*****************I would use database array here 
 res.render('restaurant', {
     restHTML: restArray
 });
```

This is incorrect as it does not push all of it to the database array in time because the code is asynchronous. My question is there a better way to access database data to be used in the ejs file or do I have to find a way to push the schema data into the databasearray and render it alongside restArray data. (I need the restArray). I want the mongoDB data to be used inside this chart.js which is in my ejs file here:

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, 
    {
      type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Chili dog", "Burger", "Zucchini Fries"], //*****************Put mongodb data inside here *******************
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Best food here:' ,
            data: [12, 19, 3], //********************Put mongodb data inside here. ******************
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }

    }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: you say you need the databaseArray, but I don't see it being used anywhere.  What is it being used for exactly?

Comment: I would most likely combine both the restArray and databaseArray to use it in the res.render. I'm not really sure on how to approach these problems as I'm new to node.js @Paul

Comment: No, I mean what do you need it for.

Comment: I updated it and put the ejs file content as well @Paul

Answer (score 1):

Start using ECMAScript 6 generators. So your code looks synchronous and the Generators + co does the asynchronous magic for you. Read more about it here http://mongoua.tk/presentations/ecmascript-6-and-the-node-driver

With Generators + co your code looks like this

```
var co = require('co');

var databaseArray = [];
co(function*() {
  var record = yeild Restaurant.findOne({nameOfRest:this.nameOfRest});
  if(!record){
    record =  yeild Restaurant.save(this);
  }
  databaseArray.push(record);
  // do other operations....
  res.render('restaurant',{restHTML:restArray});
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend he go with the 'make your code look synchronous' route (which I disagree with, but in any case), why not just go with the async/await approach, rather than adding another third party dependency?